# Taking the values of two same element

Tags: javascript

In console if I type this command:

```
document.querySelectorAll('div.information div.contact div ')[1]
```

The result I take is

```
<span class="information">
<call>number 1</call>
<call>number 2</call>
</span>
```

How can I take the innerHTML of call element? Should I use the `nth` child?
Result:

```
number 1
```

and after another command

```
number 2
```

Comment: Use `document.querySelectorAll('.information call')` which will return both the call elements..

Comment: Your selector says it selects a `<div>`. Why is the result a `<span>`?

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('div.information div.contact div span.information')[1].getElementsByTagName("time")[0].innerHTML`

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

**HTML**

```
<span class="information">
  <call>number 1</call>
  <call>number 2</call>
</span>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var values = [];
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('call');

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  values.push(elements[i].innerHTML);
}

/** ["number 1", "number 2"] **/
console.log(values);
```

**Example**

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qLhc4pzh/)

Answer (score 1):

There's no "call" element.

`document.getElementsByClassName()` is probably more appropriate in this case, but using an ID would be even easier.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var information = document.getElementsByClassName('information')[0]
  var calls = document.getElementsByClassName('call');
  var numbers = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < calls.length; i++) {
    numbers.push(calls[i].innerHTML);
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById('numbers').value += numbers[i] + '\n';
  }

}
```

```html
<span class="information">
<span class="call">number 1</span>
<span class="call">number 2</span>
</span>


<h2>Added so we can see something without looking at the console:</h2>
<form name="form" id="form">
  <textarea id="numbers"></textarea>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Practice
    </title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var data = document.getElementsByTagName("call");
        for(var i=0;i<data.length;++i)
        {
            var scope = $(data[i]).html();
            console.log(scope);
        }
    });
</script>
<body>
    <span class="information">
        <call>number 1</call>
        <call>number 2</call>
    </span>
</body>
```

Comment: He's not using jQuery. If he were, you could just use `$("call")`.